# Omnisharp issue while trying to run a Hello World Project in VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am trying to get the .Net and VSCode working on Ubuntu 20.04. "dotnet run" command does run the program ok, but running it in VSCode is giving me the following errors:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 7/7/2020, 6:28:24 PM
    Target: /home/ivlatin2012/Projects/HelloDotnetCore

OmniSharp server started with Mono 6.8.0.
    Path: /home/ivlatin2012/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1/.omnisharp/1.35.3/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 14939

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication:_validationErrorHandler' (36) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
  at OmniSharp.Stdio.StdioCommandLineApplication..ctor () [0x00000] in <11f4106bfdfd41759d0a0dc35f30dcd7>:0 
  at OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__0 () [0x00006] in <be19315b4efc4538b70abd1dc15c63a1>:0 
  at OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start (System.Func`1[TResult] action) [0x0001c] in <a3beccf5923c417282767eebc9bf25e1>:0
```

There's really not much to the Program.cs file I am running

```
using System;

namespace HelloDotnetCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

The launch.json file looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        },

        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    
    ],

    ]
}
```

The .csproj file looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I'd been away from anything .Net for the last several years, and am completely new to .Net Core. This is a part of a Pluralsight class I'm trying to follow, but have gotten stuck with VSCode & Omnisharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I could find is this

[Github issue with Mono](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1998#issuecomment-496324258)

You could try to add the setting: `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": never` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it didn't help. I forgot to mention that there was another error I was getting, too: "The preLaunch task 'build' terminated with exit code 127". Then, if I look in the VSCode terminal window, I get the: "Executing task: msbuild /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /t:build /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary <

/bin/bash: msbuild: command not found
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127". Apparently, there may be a problem where msbuild is just not being found in the current path or something similar.

Comment: Also, if I run "msbuild /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /t:build /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary" at the linux termnial, it works correctly, but I keep getting command not found error when the vscode tries to invoke msbuild through 'tasks.json'.

Comment: Does running `dotnet build` on the directory with your sln (or csproj) works? The task "build" (mentioned as preLaunch task 'build') is in .vscode/tasks.json btw.

Comment: I went ahead and compared it to my other machine that's running kubuntu 20.04, where all this works. It turned out that the symbolic link was missing on the machine where I had problems. So, I typed "sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/". It didn't fix it just yet, so I went and deleted and recreated the build task. I might have not created it correctly the first time around. Now, it is working great! Thank you all who have helped and given different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

For me, following steps worked:

- Go to C# Extension settings
- Set the Omnisharp: Use Global Mono to "Never"

[picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU5vt.png)

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, after Intellisense in VSCode inexplicably stopped working, setting this to "auto (default)" did the trick.